# Dashed line that stops when there is a node in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to write text that goes through a dotted circle such that the dashed line disappears where the text and the line meet.

I'm currently at this point in a graph I'm trying to do for a textbook.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[fill] (0,0) circle (0.2) node[above=5pt]{Kern};
\draw[dashed, red] (0,0) circle (2);
\draw[dashed, red] (0,0) circle (4);
\draw[dashed, red] (0,0) circle (6);

\draw[red, arrows = {Latex-Latex}, ultra thick] (0,-5.3) -- (0,-6.6);
\draw[red, arrows = {Latex-Latex}, ultra thick] (0,5.3) -- (0,6.6);
\draw[red, arrows = {Latex-Latex}, ultra thick] (5.3,0) -- (6.6,0);
\draw[red, arrows = {Latex-Latex}, ultra thick] (-5.3,0) -- (-6.6,0);
\draw[red, arrows = {Latex-Latex}, ultra thick, rotate = 45] (-5.3,0) -- (-6.6,0);
\draw[red, arrows = {Latex-Latex}, ultra thick, rotate = -45] (-5.3,0) -- (-6.6,0);
\draw[red, arrows = {Latex-Latex}, ultra thick, rotate = 135] (-5.3,0) -- (-6.6,0);
\draw[red, arrows = {Latex-Latex}, ultra thick, rotate = -135] (-5.3,0) -- (-6.6,0);

\node[scale = 1.3] at (3.5,2.5) {Elektronenwelle}

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Now where the text "Elektronenwelle" is the dashed lines of the circle just pass through the text. Can I make them disappear at that point, such that there is no red line through the text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace with this line and all is ok:

```
\node[scale = 1.3,fill=white] at (3.5,2.5) {Elektronenwelle};
```

Comment: @Zedssad You missed  'fill=white' and a final ';' in the line. My answer is now complete?